# No match for "operator =" when using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock

Tags: c++, c++11, timer, c++-chrono

When I compiled this *timer.hpp* header file below,
the compiler said:

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are
>   ‘std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka
>   std::chrono::time_point > >}’ and
>   ‘std::__success_type > >::type {aka std::chrono::duration >}’)
>       end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

I guess the variable type for start and end is wrong.
What is the correct type?
I want to use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

```
#include <chrono>

namespace timer{
static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start, end;

void initTime(){
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}


void endTime(){
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
}

}
```

*timer.hpp* is supposed to be used with some main file.
By calling `timer::initTime()` before some function that I want to measure and calling `timer::endTime()` after the function, I would get the timing result (the getter for the duration time is omitted here).

Comment: Here is a video tutorial for `chrono`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It addresses issues such as these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

```
static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start, end;
/* ... */

void endTime(){
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
}
```

You declare `end` as a time point, but then on the right-hand side of the assignment operator, you are subtracting two time points (`now()` and `start`), and assigning to `end`.

Logically, if you subtract two [time points](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point), you do not obtain a new time point.  For instance, if I wanted to subtract "08:15:00 today" - "08:05:00 today", it would not make sense to describe the result as "00:10:00 today".  Instead, the C++ chrono library has a [`duration` class template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration); it is intended to represent lengths of time (e.g. the difference between two time points).

See the `operator -` overload number 4 here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_arith2

I suggest watching the tutorial video that @Howard Hinnant linked to above... Mr. Hinnant was involved in developing the `std::chrono` and  `boost::chrono` libraries.

A potential *second* issue is that `start` has type `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, which may be a different type (different clock) than the type returned by `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` (which has type `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`).

Comment: Nitpick:  I'm the lead author (there were other contributors) on the `std::chrono` library which served as the basis for the `boost::chrono` library. :-)

Comment: I have changed the characterization accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  One of my points is that in this case, `std` came first and `boost` followed.  Well, at least the draft `std` came first.  The boost lib probably came about before the std went final in 2011.  This isn't really important for your good answer (which I upvoted).  These are just historical tidbits.

Comment: "08:15:00 today" - "08:05:00 today" = "00:10:00 01/01/1970", not "00:10:00 today" :P